# Using shareToFacebook method in Android

Tags: smartface.io

Can I use shareToFacebook method for Android/Android Emulator?

Comment: I edited your question to make the title more descriptive, now it's more clear what the question is about. But note that, as your question currently stands, it is pretty unclear and too broad for Stack Overflow. Please explain how you want to use that method, and show that you've done research for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use it but I suggest you to use Facebook APIs on Smartface App Studio.

I suggest you to read the articles below;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/share-function/#sharefacebook

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/facebook/

Comment: thanks, i  have  created an app from the Facebook and  filled in AppId and App Secret fields in project , but don't  work .may needed  to change anything in AndroidManifest?